# NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook

Tags: spring

I am using the Spring web framework to read an Excel file and display it. When I deploy using Tomcat I am getting this exception. I have included the (poi, ooxml) version 3.9 jar file.

**Exception**

> HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>           org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
>           ExcelReader.constructObject(ExcelReader.java:42)
>           ExcelReportController.handleRequestInternal(ExcelReportController.java:32)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>           org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.33 logs.

Comment: Can you check whether the poi library is added to the deployment assembly of the server configuration?

Comment: actually i am using the Netbean IDE, which mostly take's care by adding library. please correct me if am wrong.